# State machine with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

I want to implement mulistep(wizard type) forms to signup. I used Rails 3.1. I need to achieve with help of state machine, so I can maintain it easily. But I am confused with active-record with state-machine. Could please share resources that help my work.

Comment: There are many ways to implement a multistep forms, some using state machine, some using other methods, e.g. [Railscast #217](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms). Can you improve the quality of the question by giving more details on what is it that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try [ https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/ ]

Answer (score 0):

There are few gems available for the implementation of state machines in Rails.

state_machine: It's the most downloaded gem in this category. But unfortunately this feature packed option is no longer maintained.

aasm: AASM aka ‘acts_as_state_machine’ is the second most popular gem in the list as per the download count goes. AASM is regularly maintained by an active community and comes with a very nice documentation.

You can check this Medium article for more details:
https://medium.com/geogo-in/state-machines-in-rails-5-45259a4f42da